# Check Linux Pagecache Entry Validity

Tags: caching, memory-management, concurrency, linux-kernel, filesystems

I used [`find_get_entries()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.7/source/mm/filemap.c#L1724) to **retrieve** pagecache pages associated with **all** opened files. For **each** retrieved page, a [`put_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.7/source/include/linux/mm.h#L1036) invocation will be needed to **revert** the page *reference count* to its previous state. `find_get_entries()` seems to be **racy**. In some scenarios, the returned `struct page *` element contains **garbage** (perhaps because the **page** associated with an **index** has been **evicted**). Therefore, a `put_page()` call on **such** a page will cause kernel **panic**. How can I **avoid** this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the **shadow** entries of *recently* **evicted** pages, etc. (recognized by [calling `xa_is_value()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.7/source/mm/filemap.c#L1744)) will also be **returned** in the `entries` parameter. They can be **identified and ignored** by checking their *LSB* (i.e., if `(unsigned long)entries[i] & 1` is **not** zero, the element is **not** a valid page).